# How to define a JSON schema that requires at least one of many properties

Tags: json, jsonschema

I would like to know if I can define a JSON schema (draft 4) that requires at least one of many properties possible for an object. I already know of `allOf`, `anyOf` and `oneOf` but just can't figure out how to use them in the way I want.

Here are some example JSON to illustrate :

```
// Test Data 1 - Should pass
{

    "email": "hello@example.com",
    "name": "John Doe"
}
// Test Data 2 - Should pass
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jane Doe"
}
// Test Data 3 - Should pass
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "hello@example.com",
    "name": "John Smith"
}
// Test Data 4 - Should fail, invalid email
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "thisIsNotAnEmail",
    "name": "John Smith"
}

// Test Data 5 - Should fail, missing one of required properties
{
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

I would like to require at least `id` or `email` (also accepting both of them) and still pass validation according to format. Using `oneOf` fails validation if I provide both (test 3), `anyOf` passes validation even if one of them is not valid (test 4)

Here is my schema :

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "id": "https://example.com",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "email"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can you help me how to achieve correct validation for my use case ?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

To require at least one of a set of properties, use `required` inside a series of `anyOf` options:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "anyOf": [
        {"required": ["id"]},
        {"required": ["email"]}
        // any other properties, in a similar way
    ],
    "properties": {
        // Your actual property definitions here
    }
}
```

If any of the properties you want is present (`"id"`, `"email"`), then it will pass the corresponding option in `allOf`.

Answer (score 41):

You may use `minProperties: number` (and `maxProperties: number` if needed).
That would shorten the schema definition:

```
{
     type: "object",
     minProperties: 1,
     properties: [/* your actual properties definitions */],
     additionalProperties: false
}
```

Link to documentation: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#size

Comment: This is actually a bad solution, because an object, that contains none of the properties defined in the schema while having properties that are not present in the schema, will still validate. Example: `{ "foo": "bar" }` will validate against `{ "type": "object", "minProperties": 1, "properties": { "test": { "type": "string" }, "bar": { "type": "string" } } }`.

Comment: @Benni what about `"additionalProperties": false` then?

Comment: That would work. Read more [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#properties).