# JSON Schema: How to enforce oneOf for objects at different nesting levels?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I've recently learned ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839578/how-to-define-a-json-schema-that-requires-at-least-one-of-many-properties), [this](https://queirozf.com/entries/json-schema-examples), and [this](https://gist.github.com/rolaveric/01c77c5db2183fc26ffd), among other resources) how to use the `oneOf` keyword to declare JSON validity only when one among many elements is present at the same nesting level. E.g., the following schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "req1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "req2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "obj": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "req1": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    { "required": ["req1"] },
    { "required": ["req2"] }
  ]
}
```

...ensures that the following are valid json:

```
{ "req1": "foo", "obj": { "req1": "foo" } }
```

```
{ "req2": "foo", "obj": { "req1": "foo" } }
```

...and the following is not because **both** `req1` and `req2` are present, rather than *one of* `req1` and `req2`:

```
{ "req1": "foo", "req2": "foo", "obj": { "req1": "foo" } }
```

I'm failing at extrapolating from this example to enforcing the "one-of required" concept to elements at different nesting levels. E.g. **how can I enforce that one of `req1` and `obj.req1` are required?**

Answer (score 0):

> E.g. how can I enforce that one of req1 and obj.req1 are required?

```
...
"oneOf": [
  {
    "required": [ "req1" ]
  },
  {
    "required": [ "obj" ],
    "properties": {
      "obj": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [ req1 ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```