# Make a group of attributes of which only 1 is required be reflected in the schema in Pydantic

Tags: python-3.x, validation, jsonschema, pydantic

I want to as the title says create a group of attributes `a`, `b` and `c`, such that any combination can be supplied as long as one is given. I have managed to achieve the functionality but it is not reflected in the schema which is what I can't manage to do.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator

class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str | None = None
    b: str | None = None
    c: str | None = None

    @root_validator
    def check_at_least_one_given(cls, values):
        if not any((values.get('a'), values.get('b'), values.get('c'))):
            raise ValueError("At least of a, b, or c must be given")
        return values

# Doesn't have required fields
print(Foo.schema_json(indent=2))
```

```json
{
  "title": "Foo",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "title": "A",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "b": {
      "title": "B",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "c": {
      "title": "C",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

```py
# No error
print(Foo(a="1"))
>>> a='1' b=None c=None
print(Foo(b="2"))
>>> a=None b='2' c=None
print(Foo(c="3"))
>>> a=None b=None c='3'
print(Foo(a="1", b="2"))
>>> a='1' b='2' c=None
print(Foo(a="1", c="3"))
>>> a='1' b=None c='3'
print(Foo(b="2", c="3"))
>>> a=None b='2' c='3'
print(Foo(a="1", b="2", c="3"))
>>> a='1' b='2' c='3'

# Invalid
Foo()
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 342, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
__root__
  At least of a, b, or c must be given (type=value_error)
```

I want the schema to output something like

```json
{
  "title": "Foo",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "title": "A",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "b": {
      "title": "B",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "c": {
      "title": "C",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    ["a", "b", "c"]
  ]
}
```

or something else that (probably) more clearly expresses the intent of **at least one of these is required**.

Is this possible and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Pydantic does not have a built in mechanism for this. And the validation logic you provide in a custom validator will never find its way into the JSON schema. You could try and search through and if unsuccessful post a feature request for something like this in their [issue tracker](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues).

The JSON schema core specification defines the [`anyOf`](http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#name-anyof) keyword, which takes subschemas to validate against. This allows specifying the `required` keyword once for each of your fields in its own subschema. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31841897/19770795) for details and an example.

In the Pydantic `Config` you can utilize [`schema_extra`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/#schema-customization) to extend the auto-generated schema. Here is an example of how you can write a corresponding workaround:

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str | None = None
    b: str | None = None
    c: str | None = None

    @root_validator
    def check_at_least_one_given(cls, values: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        if all(
            (v is None for v in (values.get("a"), values.get("b"), values.get("c")))
        ):
            raise ValueError("Any one of `a`, `b`, or `c` must be given")
        return values

    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
            assert "anyOf" not in schema, "Oops! What now?"
            schema["anyOf"] = [
                {"required": ["a"]},
                {"required": ["b"]},
                {"required": ["c"]},
            ]
            for prop in schema.get("properties", {}).values():
                prop.pop("title", None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Foo.schema_json(indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "title": "Foo",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "b": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "c": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "a"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "b"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "c"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This conforms to the specs and expresses your custom validation.

But note that I put in that `assert` to indicate that I have no strong basis to assume that the automatic schema will not provide its own `anyOf` key at some point, which would greatly complicate things. Consider this an unstable solution.

**Side note**:

Be careful with the `any` check in your validator. An empty string is *"falsy"* just like `None`, which might lead to unexpected results, depending on whether you want to consider empty strings to be valid values in this context or not. `any(v for v in ("", 0, False, None))` is `False`.

I adjusted your validator in my code to explicitly check against `None` for this reason.